# Hibernate can't save entity without renaming

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have very strange problem and I can't understand it's reason.

I tried to save simple Object (Group.class) with only 1 field (@id groupName), getter and setter.
When I try to run my program, I have an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC
>   batch update  at
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '**Group (groupName) values
>   ('Test')' at line 1**

But if I specify the name of entity (different of Group) all works fine.
Could you please explain me what I've done wrong?

Code:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping class="com.globallogic.dto.Group"></mapping>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>

import javax.persistence.*;
```

Group.class

```
@Entity //this doesn't work
//@Entity(name = "SomeName") // this works good
public class Group {

    @Id
    private String groupName;

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;

    }

}
```

DataSender.class

```
public class DataSender {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public DataSender() {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }
    public void sendData(Object... objects) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        if (session.isConnected()) {

            System.out.println("ALL IS GOOD");
            session.beginTransaction();

            for (Object user: objects) {
                session.persist(user);
            }
            System.out.println();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            System.out.println("Connection is closed");
        }

        sessionFactory.close();
    }

}
```

Main.class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        DataSender ds = new DataSender();

        Group group = new Group();
        group.setGroupName("Test");
        ds.sendData(group);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group` is an SQL keyword, you'll need to [quote your table name](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`Group`")
public class Group {
  ....
```

Comment: Ermmm.. ok, thank you (when I created Group table manually, using MySQL workbench, it works fine)

Comment: It might be that MySQL workbench automatically quotes identifiers.